# Most useful Rails plugins, Ruby libraries and Ruby gems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, wiki, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I have seen many sites which provide the whole list of `Rails plugins`, `Ruby libraries` and `Ruby gems`, but we hardly use few of them and some may not suit our requirement and we spend a whole lot of time searching for useful `Plugins` which suits our requirement.

I have created this poll, people can post useful libraries, `gems and plugins` which they have come across.  It would be great help for newbies like me and to the entire `Ruby` on `Rails community`.

**Note:** to keep this poll as useful as possible, please remember:

- Post only one library, gem, or plugin per answer
- Mention the name of the library, gem, or plugin which you find it useful.
- URL of the location of the resource
- We don't want duplicate answers, so before posting check if the library has been mentioned already.

**Edit:**  Any new plugins/Gems for Rails 3 ?

Thanks!

Comment: Here is my list of gems in development group that helps to make things faster or sometimes bring simplicity to the development process
http://www.codebeerstartups.com/2013/04/must-have-gems-for-development-machine-in-ruby-on-rails/

Answer (score 21):

**[Will Paginate](http://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/tree/master)** - essential for pagination.

Answer (score 19):

[HAML](http://haml-lang.com/) and [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/)

Comment: disagree with this, I think most people (especially on large projects) would rather have their html as html.

Comment: The question didn't say large projects 8) And most people I know working on large Rails based projects ten to use HAML and SASS.

Comment: How many of the people who work on these projects are people who come from a completely front end background. JUST XHTML and CSS? Even if its 1, the benefits(?) of HAML and SASS are negated by that person who spent their entire career learning CSS and XHTML because of the differences in Syntax.

Comment: Luckily this question was tagged "subjective" as in your opionion it's not good, but in mine it is very good. Vote up the gems/plugins that you do like 8)

Comment: I love HAML and SASS. You get much more readable views with it. You also can't miss closing your tags while using it over (X)HTML, since it does it for you. All in all, it's worth the extra 20 minutes it'll take a designer to learn.

Comment: Indeed, I've used HTML -> XHTML -> CSS for over 10 years, and HAML made me finally fall in love with my job 8) Even so, I teach use of ERB and HTML and add HAML for students to choose as they feel more comfortable.

Answer (score 18):

**[devise](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2009/10/devise-flexible-authentication-solution-for-rails/)** - a more comprehensive authentication gem

Answer (score 17):

**[Authlogic](http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic/)** - Easy Authentication

Comment: +1 for Authlogic .Please provide the link to the Resource , so that i would be helpful for users ,Thanks

Answer (score 15):

**[Formtastic](http://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic/tree/master)** - Awsome form helpers.

It lets you do things like this:

```
<% semantic_form_for @user do |f| %>
    <% f.inputs do %>
        <%= f.input :email %>
        <%= f.input :password %>
        <%= f.input :password_confirmation %>
    <% end %>

    <% f.buttons do %>
        <%= f.commit_button 'Sign Up' %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

and get decent, semantic HTML:

Comment: Never seen this before - I'll have to take a look through!

Comment: I stumbled across this the other day in a thoughtbot blog post, figured I'd see if anyone had mentioned it on SO.  This really is one of the best plugins I've ever used.  It is so awesome it hurts.

Answer (score 15):

**[Rspec](http://rspec.info/)** - for BDD.

Answer (score 14):

[FactoryGirl](http://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl) :  Fixture replacement for focused and readable tests.

Answer (score 13):

**[Paperclip](http://www.thoughtbot.com/projects/paperclip)** - Simple file uploads

Answer (score 11):

[**Nokogiri**](http://nokogiri.org/) - for all your XML and HTML parsing and searching needs.

Answer (score 9):

**[Capistrano](http://capify.org)** - for easy deployment.

Answer (score 9):

**[Faker](http://www.rubyinside.com/faker-quick-fake-data-generation-in-ruby-665.html)** - for creating valid, fake data. Great for populating an empty dev DB / testing.

Answer (score 9):

Annotate - simple gem which adds something like

```
#== Schema Information
#
#Table name: buttons
#id           :integer(4)      not null, primary key
#text         :string(255)
#font_size    :integer(4)
#user_id      :integer(4)
#created_at   :datetime
#updated_at   :datetime
#button_stats :integer(4)      default(0), not null
```

to your model definitions and fixtures

Answer (score 7):

**[Thinking Sphinx](http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/)** - for integrating with Sphinx for dead-simple text-searching in your app.

Answer (score 6):

[Clearance](http://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance) for authentication.

Comment: Are you sure it's really good? I mean compared to other auth gems?

Answer (score 5):

**[Populator](http://populator.rubyforge.org/)** - for pushing data into the DB when populating it. Used in conjunction with Faker. [More info here](http://neilmiddleton.com/2009/04/28/faking-data-in-your-rails-app-with-faker-and-populator/).

Answer (score 5):

[**cancan**](http://github.com/ryanb/cancan) - for roles, companion of authlogic

Answer (score 4):

**[Capistrano-ext](http://github.com/jamis/capistrano-ext/tree/master)** - allows you to setup separate deploy recipes for staging / production / whatever other environment you have

Answer (score 4):

Seed-Fu - Easy database seeding gem. Please don't use migrations to seed your database! :)

Comment: We use a combination of populator and faker for this. Need to take a closer look at Seed-Fu.

Answer (score 4):

**[prawn](http://wiki.github.com/sandal/prawn/)** - PDF generation

Answer (score 4):

### [Cucumber](http://cukes.info/) - BDD and testing

It lets software development teams describe how software should behave in plain text. The text is written in a business-readable domain-specific language and serves as documentation, automated tests and development-aid - all rolled into one format.

Answer (score 3):

grosser-rpx_now - Interface into RPXNow.com, which provides an interface into OpenID, Facebook, MySpace, Twitter, and much more in terms of authentication. A great companion for Authlogic.

Answer (score 3):

[**Mofo**](http://mofo.rubyforge.org/) gem  -  A ruby microformat parser  , Helps to import Profile data from networking sites which implements microformats  using hResume,hCard . ex LinkedIn , Xing ,Twitter  etc .

Very useful gem .

Answer (score 3):

`soap4r`: A must have for making soap calls!

Source: http://rubyforge.org/projects/soap4r/

Comment: Please provide the link to the Resource , so that it would be helpful for users ,Thanks

Answer (score 3):

[Contacts](http://github.com/cardmagic/contacts/tree/master)  is a universal interface to grab contact list information from various providers including Hotmail, Gmail and 
Yahoo.

Answer (score 3):

[jRails](http://github.com/aaronchi/jrails) is a drop-in jQuery replacement for the Rails Prototype/script.aculo.us helpers.

Answer (score 3):

[Delayed Job](http://github.com/tobi/delayed_job) for background processing.

Answer (score 3):

**[calendar_date_select](http://code.google.com/p/calendardateselect/)** - calendar pop-up

Answer (score 3):

**[thin](http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/)**, a *faster* http server

Answer (score 3):

### [Webrat](http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/testing/webrat) - testing

is a Ruby integration test library. It has two main purposes:

1. Implement a browser simulator to allow fast, reliable integration testing (sans JavaScript) without requiring Selenium or Watir and their associated issues.
2. Define a ubiquitous DSL for describing interacting with a web application from the perspective of an end user.

Answer (score 3):

[simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) - built on top of formtastic, and despite its name it's even better giving you better control (by being agnostic) over layout and everything is configurable.  I'm surprised it wasn't listed already as it's very popular.

Answer (score 2):

**[Validation Reflection](http://github.com/redinger/validation_reflection/tree/master)** - when used with formtastic, it frees you from having to specify which fields of a form are required, as it infers it from your model validations.

Answer (score 2):

**[Nested Layouts](http://nested-layouts.rubyforge.org/)** - Great when you have sections of your site that sit inside their own wrappers. My account (in many apps) has a series of controllers that may have a common navigation header. Nested layouts allows you to use a my_account layout that sits inside your application layout, preventing the need for duplicate layout code or spurious navigation partials.

Comment: This was broken as of Rails 2.2 but I fixed it in my fork of it: http://github.com/radar/by_star

Answer (score 2):

I really enjoy [harsh](http://carboni.ca/projects/harsh/) for syntax highlighting.  It gives you access to all of the TextMate themes also, which I love.

Answer (score 2):

**[More](http://github.com/cloudhead/more)**, the rails plugin for [Less](http://lesscss.org/), the CSS extension. I prefer Less to Haml; there's no learning curve for Less.

Answer (score 1):

**[Backup-fu](http://code.google.com/p/backup-fu/)** - in conjuction with capistrano, we always backup before a deploy to Amazon S3, and set cron jobs that periodically backup the database and asset directories.

Answer (score 1):

[state_machine](http://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine/): adds support for creating state machines with a lot of very useful features. It has great ActiveRecord integration and even supports automatic named scope for states.

Answer (score 1):

[tracked_plugins](http://github.com/grosser/tracked_plugins) keeps track of plugin install information/updates/local-modification for all plugins you install

Answer (score 1):

Oddly self-serving but I find these helpful:

[**by_star**](http://github.com/radar/by_star) - Helpful for finding records based on time ranges.
[**lookup**](http://github.com/radar/lookup) - Ever wanted to look up a Rails method in the API from the command line?

Use `lookup has_many` to be taken to [that method in the API.](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#M001833) Also supports fuzzy matching.

Answer (score 1):

[youtube-g](http://youtube-g.rubyforge.org/) is a pure Ruby client for the YouTube GData API. It provides an easy way to access the latest YouTube video search results from your own programs

Answer (score 1):

[**smerf**](http://smerf.cascadia.com.au/) - dynamic forms for surveys and questionnaires

Answer (score 1):

[Savage Beast 2](http://code.google.com/p/savage-beast-2/)   Based on the very popular Rails message forum, Beast, this is a Rails forum that implements multiple topics, posts, moderators, RSS feeds, localization, and most all the niceties you've gotten to know on the Beast forums.

Answer (score 1):

[Spree](https://github.com/spree/spree) - open source e-commerce solution for Ruby on Rails

Answer (score 0):

[ruote](http://openwferu.rubyforge.org/download.html)  - Work flow Engine in Rails