# How to search for useful ruby gems

Tags: ruby, rubygems

What are good sites to look for useful ruby gems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [Github](http://www.github.com/) is where most gems source code is hosted; they have a search facility, and you can search by language as well.

Answer (score 7):

- [Agile Web Development](http://agilewebdevelopment.com/) lists plugins (though not rubygems, I'm not sure why), and allows people to give ratings for them.
- [Ruby Toolbox](http://ruby-toolbox.com/) lists gems by category and compares how popular they are.
- [Rubygems](http://rubygems.org/) has a search box.
- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141998/most-useful-rails-plugins-ruby-libraries-and-ruby-gems) has a question on most useful rails plugins and rubygems.

Answer (score 0):

I have compiled a list of usefull gems for development machine. You can check the list [here with detailed explaination](http://www.codebeerstartups.com/2013/04/must-have-gems-for-development-machine-in-ruby-on-rails/)

```
  gem "better_errors"
  gem "binding_of_caller"
  gem 'annotate'
  gem 'bullet'
  gem 'debugger'
  gem 'flay'
  gem 'hirb'
  gem 'localtunnel'
  gem 'lol_dba'
  gem 'mailcatcher'
  gem 'meta_request','0.2.1'
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'pry-doc'
  gem 'quiet_assets'
  gem 'rack-mini-profiler'
  gem 'railroady'
  gem 'rails-footnotes', '>= 3.7.5.rc4'
  gem 'rails_best_practices'
  gem 'reek'
  gem 'request-log-analyzer'
  gem 'smusher'
  gem 'zeus' # don't add this in your gemfile.
```