# Rails newbie, is there as website that categorizes / sorts / reviews rubygems / plugins etc?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to search for useful ruby gems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085050/how-to-search-for-useful-ruby-gems)

Hi,

As a beginner to ruby / rails, I can see there is a bunch of gems etc that would be of value to me. How to explore these all at once?

rubygems.org doesn't seem to categorize / review? am I missing something obvious? A better site for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check [Ruby Tool Box](http://ruby-toolbox.com/)

Comment: Unfortunately, it is outdated. Fortunately, Christoph will release version 2.0 soon :)