# Must know Ruby on Rails + Ruby plugins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm fairly new in the Ruby + Rails scene. Although I have a very strong understanding of design patterns, data structures and algorithms - there's a ton of "must have" plugins that I haven't had a chance to run into yet. There's things for migrations, resource controllers and a myriad of other plugins that make developing for these platforms significantly easier.

Would anyone be kind enough to share links for some of the most commonly used ones that every savvy Ruby or Ruby on Rails developer knows about. Something that's so important, that it might even be considered to be merged into the core at some point.

Hope that's appropriate for this forum. I surely think it is.

Comment: There's no such thing as ruby plugins as far as I know, only (Ruby on) Rails plugins and ruby gems.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Most useful Rails plugins, Ruby libraries and Ruby  gems?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141998/most-useful-rails-plugins-ruby-libraries-and-ruby-gems)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Ruby Toolbox](http://ruby-toolbox.com/) is another invaluable resource for Ruby and Rails developers

Comment: Nice, how had I not seen that before?  Awesome resource!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the link for rails top rated plugin.

http://agilewebdevelopment.com/plugins/top_rated

Answer (score 1):

You can find all top rated plugin at github.
Example:-These are some most usable plugins

http://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip
 2.http://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on
 3.http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic

Answer (score 0):

[RailsGems.org](http://railsgems.org/) looks like it will be a useful site.