# Can i get Ruby on Rails components List?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, zend-framework

I'm a PHP developer on Zend framework.
I'm checking ROR.

Can i get Ruby on Rails components List? 
Like in ZF: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.6/en/requirements.zendcomponents.html

Answer (score 0):

In rails, the main components to be noticed are as:

1. configuration for your app
2. gems with specific version, required for your app(available at rubygems.org)
3. routes information for your app
4. scaffolding and generators in your app
5. three different environment for your app, as Development, Testing, Production
6. testing strategies for your app, like unit test, functional tests
7. Databases settings for your different-2 environments, and database engine like sqlite, mysql, postgres
8. server to run your app
9. management of your assests in app/assests folder
10. Methods to deploy your app and much more......

    In addition, You should go through these  [slides](http://www.slideshare.net/ifuturz/get-aware-of-ruby-on-rails-components)

    and this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141998/most-useful-rails-plugins-ruby-libraries-and-ruby-gems) also contains a lot info for important rails component.

Answer (score 0):

For Rails there isn't any official list like the Zend one you linked. I use Google, or sometimes [The Ruby Toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/)

Answer (score 0):

The rails components are packed as gems, to get the full list of gems go to http://rubygems.org/gems

Then there are some sites like [Ruby Toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/) that help you choosing by providing statistics about usage and development.

Gather a list of requirements and then search if there is already a gem providing that functionality.